# how to fire 'profile_update' hook on adding/removing roles from wp-admin/users.php page? (or what other hook to use in this case)

Tags: php, wordpress, hook, multiple-users

### Background

On adding a specific role (referee) to a profile I add a *profile page* on a custom post type and link it to that user with a meta value on both the post and the user. I also check if a user has previously been that role (by a meta value on that user) and then add/ edit their *profile page* accordingly. 
All of that works fine when I add the role from the user-edit page

`http://localhost:8888/wp-admin/user-edit.php?user_id={SOME USER ID}`

### Problem

But when the role is added(or removed) from the **bulk-actions / actions** buttons on `/wp-admin/users.php`([Edit page reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lPF7.png)) the `profile_update` hook doesn't get triggered.
 So is there a way I could either extend the `profile_update` to include updates from the `/wp-admin/users.php` **or** remove the actions buttons from `/wp-admin/users.php` altogether (or some other solution)?

**Atempts at solving**

I was able to remove the bulk-actions button with this filter `add_filter('bulk_actions-users','__return_empty_array');`
 but couldn't find a a filter to remove the action buttons on the right.

---

### Code in question

```
function site_refProfile_existingUser( $user_id, $old_user_data ){
  if ((get_user_meta( $user_id, 'wp_capabilities')[0]['referee'] !== null) && (metadata_exists('user', $user_id, 'ref_pageID'))) {
    $profileID = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'ref_pageID')[0];
    $postUpdateArgs = array(
      'ID'          => $profileID,
      'post_status' => "private"
    );
    wp_update_post($postUpdateArgs);
    error_log("making profile :".$profileID." private (User : ".$user_id.")");
  }
  elseif ((get_user_meta( $user_id, 'wp_capabilities')[0]['referee'] == null) && (!metadata_exists('user', $user_id, 'ref_pageID'))) {
    $refProfileName = "".get_user_meta( $user_id, 'first_name')[0]." ".get_user_meta( $user_id, 'last_name')[0]."";
    if(substr($refProfileName,-1)== 's'){
      $refProfileNameCleaned = $refProfileName."' ";
    } else{
      $refProfileNameCleaned = $refProfileName."'s ";
    }
    $refProfileArgs = array(
      'post_title'       =>  $refProfileNameCleaned."Profile",
      'post_excerpt'     => "Read {$refProfileNameCleaned}profile on Bootle Referees' Association's official website",
      'post_name'        => $refProfileName,
      'post_type'        => "refprofile",
      'post_status'      => "publish",
      'post_author'      => $user_id,
    );
    $refProfilePost = wp_insert_post($refProfileArgs);
    update_post_meta( $refProfilePost, 'profile_refID', $user_id);
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'ref_pageID', $refProfilePost);
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'user_url', get_the_permalink($refProfilePost));
    error_log("Creating profile :".$profileID." (User : ".$user_id.")");
  }
  elseif ((get_user_meta( $user_id, 'wp_capabilities')[0]['referee'] == null) && (metadata_exists('user', $user_id, 'ref_pageID'))) {
    $profileID = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'ref_pageID')[0];
    $postUpdateArgs = array(
      'ID'          => $profileID,
      'post_status' => "publish"
    );
    wp_update_post($postUpdateArgs);
    error_log("Publishing profile :".$profileID." (User : ".$user_id.")");
  }
}
add_action( 'profile_update', 'site_refProfile_existingUser',10, 2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update: Found solution**

So I don't think the `profile_update` hook works the way its supposed to or I am using it wrong either way. what I found was that `profile_update` fired before the updates to the post/user were pushed, which meant if i was to check the values of the meta they would be the old ones, even though in the [WP Docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/profile_update/) it says it passes on the old values for the user as a variable to the called function which i amused meant that if I query for a metavalue in the function it would be the updated one.

If you need a hook which checks if any `metavalue` on any `post type` (even user) and more importantly fires **AFTER** the update is pushed to the data tables use `updated_{YOUR POST TYPE}_meta` ([WP Docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_user_meta/)).

so instead of

```
add_action( 'profile_update', 'site_refProfile_existingUser', 10, 2);
```

I used this

```
add_action( 'updated_user_meta', 'site_refProfile_existingUser',10, 2);
```

Also make sure in your function you `remove_action` at the start and `add_action` at the end if you are updating the meta of the user otherwise i assume it will get stuck in a infinite loop

```
function site_refProfile_existingUser( $meta_id, $user_id) {
    remove_action( 'updated_user_meta', 'site_refProfile_existingUser',10, 2);

    // your code.....

    add_action( 'updated_user_meta', 'site_refProfile_existingUser',10, 2);
}
```

(The infinite loop thing is an assumption as its happened to me before while using another hook)

Comment: isn't your recursion problem in your example caused by having the add_action inside the function instead of outside the function where add_action normally belongs?